# cron syntax for date

Tags: unix, date, cron

The following statement work at command prompt. But does not work in a cron.

```
myvar=`date +'%d%m'`; echo $myvar >> append.txt
```

The cron log shows that only a part of the date statement is run.
How do I use it in a cron?

Comment: Probably more appropriate for serverfault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the percent signs with a backslash (`\%`).

Answer (score 1):

My general rule of thumb is "do not write scripts in the crontab file".  That means I don't place anything other than a simple script name (with absolute path) and possibly some control arguments in the crontab file.  In particular, I do not place I/O redirection or variable evaluations in the crontab file; such things go in a (shell) script run by the cron job.

This avoids the trouble - and works across a wide variety of variants of cron, both ancient and modern.

Answer (score 1):

from `man 5 crontab`:

> The sixth field (the rest of the
>   line) specifies the command to be run.
>   The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or % character, will be
>   executed by /bin/sh or by
>        the shell specified in the SHELL variable of the cronfile. 
>   Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (), will be changed into
>   newline characters, and all
>        data after the first % will be sent to the command as standard input.

Your `%`s are being changed to newlines, and the latter part of your command is being fed to the command as stdin. As Ignacio says, you need to escape the `%`s with a `\`